# AWS lambda websocket implementation using custom domain name has POST issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API gateway websocket lambda implementation.  I have connected a custom domain to the API gateway.  I am able to connect and disconnect just fine.  But when I try to post messages using the AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi the custom domain name is causing a problem.

I **was** building the endpoint using parms, as follows:

```
const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
    endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
  });
```

And then calling it as follows:

```
await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ ConnectionId: connectionId, Data: postData }).promise();
```

This resulted in an error as follows:

```
2021-01-07T09:56:12.751Z    846f4674-0ed9-422b-8b35-64f0c43a10de    INFO    NotFoundException: No method found matching route test/@connections/YxcdBcOkrPECHwA= for http method POST.
    at Object.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12) {
  code: 'NotFoundException',
  time: 2021-01-07T09:56:12.712Z,
  requestId: '43b744b9-25ef-4a15-82ed-6ecb13062208',
  statusCode: 404,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 64.57971601177839
}
```

I then changed the code to use a hard-coded value for the AWS gateway endpoint, which looks like **this** (actual id ogjkythg67m changed for privacy):

```
const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
    endpoint: "https://ogjkythg67m.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/test"
  });
```

At this point everything started working.

So, it seems that I can't use the `event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage` vars to build my endpoint when using a custom domain.

I don't really want to hard-code the endpoint into the code.  Is there any way to configure my AWS API gateway or lambda definition to leverage the custom domain name, or circumvent the issue in some other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party I'm sure,
This happened to me today, I'd just built upon the sample provided by AWS.

there they also append the stage like your code above

```
const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
apiVersion: '2018-11-29',
endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
```

});

To fix, you simply remove the code that appends the stage

```
 + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
```

then it works fine with the custom domain

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

```
NotFoundException: No method found matching route test/@connections/YxcdBcOkrPECHwA= for http method POST.
```

so `/@connections/YxcdBcOkrPECHwA=` is somehow being appended to the endpoint. Looks like the [websocket documenation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-how-to-call-websocket-api-connections.html) confirms this.

Log `event.requestContext.stage` to confirm this yourself. The documentation doesn't seem to cover this, so you'll have to inspect `event.requestContext` by logging it to see if another field with just the stage is provided, or provide some string manipulation to strip the rest of that path.

Comment: Thanks Henry.  That's expected - it pops /@connections/{connectionId} on the end for each POST request.  That part of the process is fine - the whole thing works if I supply hard-coded values for {domainName}/{stage} so the append of /@connections... is as required.  It just doesn't work if I use the event.requestContext.domainName value (which is set to my custom domain name).

Comment: if you log `event.requestContext.domainName` does it print _exactly_ the same as the domain you hardcode? It would be good to see the values logged side-by-side with the hardcoded equivalent.

Comment: The event.requestContext.domainName value is the custom domain name (e.g. mydomain.com) - this is the specific issue.  That value does not work.  The ws API can be accessed from both the custom domain name AND the AWS default domain name.  The AWS name works, the custom one doesn't.  The format of each is 'correct', but AWS does not cope when I use the custom one.

Comment: I think the [custom domain documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) implies if you _don't_ have a base path mapping then the custom domain maps to the full base URL (including stage) of the API. This means you would drop the stage part of the path entirely when using the custom domain. Are you using any base path mappings?

Comment: Thanks Henry - I tried all sorts of combinations of strings to get the custom domain to work.  In the end I've opted to use the native AWS endpoint url which does work for outbound traffic even when the inbound traffic has arrived over the custom domain name route.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: For me the fix to this error was to use `endpoint: 'https://' + domainName + '/'` (without any path after it) and make sure domainName is correct. Your code referencing the custom domain seems to be missing the protocol.

Comment: Just remove the part of the code that appends the stage and you should be good to go